# Trouble with pulling distinct data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok this is hard to explain partially because I'm bad at sql but this code isn't doing exactly what I want it to do. I'll try to explain what it is supposed to do as best I can and hopefully someone can spot a glaring mistake. I'm sorry about the long winded explanation but there is a lot going on here and I really could use the help.

The point of this script is to search for parts which need to be obsoleted. in other words they haven't been used in three years and are still active.

When we obsolete part, "part.status" is set to 'O'. It is normally null. Also, the word 'OBSOLETE' is usually written in to "part.description"

The "WORK_ORDER" contains every scheduled work order. These are defined by base,lot, and sub ID's. It also contains many dates such as the date when the work order was closed.

the "REQUIREMENT" table contains all the parts require for each job. many jobs may require multiple parts, some at different legs of the job. The way this is handled is that for a given "REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID" and "REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_LOT_ID", they may be listed on a dozen or so subsequent rows. Each line specifies a different "REQUIREMENT.PART_ID". The sub id separates what leg of the job that the part is needed. All of the parts I care about start with 'PCH'

When I run this code it returns 14 lines, I happen to know it should be returning about 39 right now. I believe the screwy part starts at line 17. I found that code on another form hoping that it would help solve the original problem. Without that code, I get like 27K lines because the DB is pulling every criteria matching requirement from every criteria matching work order. Many of these parts are used on multiple jobs. I've also tried using DISTINCT on REQUIREMENT.PART_ID which seems like it should solve the problem. Alas it doesn't.

So I know despite all the information I probably still didn't give nearly enough. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT
PART.ID [Engr Master]
,PART.STATUS [Master Status]
,WO.CLOSE_DATE  
,PT.ID  [Die]
,PT.STATUS  [Die Status]

FROM PART
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT 
    WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID
    ,WORK_ORDER.LOT_ID
    ,WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID
    ,WORK_ORDER.PART_ID
    ,WORK_ORDER.CLOSE_DATE
    FROM WORK_ORDER
    WHERE 
        GETDATE() - (360*3) > WORK_ORDER.CLOSE_DATE
        AND PART.ID = WORK_ORDER.PART_ID
        AND PART.STATUS ='O'
    )WO
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
    REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
    ,REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_LOT_ID
    ,REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
    ,REQUIREMENT.PART_ID
FROM REQUIREMENT
WHERE
    WO.BASE_ID = REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
    AND WO.LOT_ID = REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_LOT_ID
    AND WO.SUB_ID = REQUIREMENT.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
    AND REQUIREMENT.PART_ID LIKE 'PCH%'

)REQ
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT
    PART.ID
    ,PART.STATUS
FROM PART
WHERE 
    REQ.PART_ID = PART.ID
    AND PART.STATUS IS NULL

)PT
ORDER BY PT.ID
```

Comment: Can you add sample data, what you are getting from above query and what is your expected output to the question ? That will make lot of things easier to understand

Comment: See Below. There is a link.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to understand without any sample data, but I took a stab at it anyway. I removed the second JOIN to PART (that had alias PART1) as it seemed unecessary. I also removed the subquery that was looking for parts HAVING COUNT(PART_ID) = 1

The first JOIN to PART should be done on REQUIREMENT.PART_ID = PART.PART_ID as the relationship as already been defined from WORK_ORDER to REQUIREMENT, hence you can JOIN PART directly to REQUIREMENT at this point.

**EDIT 03/23/2015**
If I understand this correctly, you just need a distinct list of PCH parts, and their respective last (read: MAX) CLOSE_DATE. If that is the case, here is what I propose.

I broke the query up into a couple of CTE's. The first CTE is simply going through the PART table and pulling out a DISTINCT list of PCH parts, grouping by PART_ID and DESCRIPTION.

The second CTE, is going through the REQUIREMENT table, joining to the WORK_ORDER table and, for each PART_ID (handled by the PARTITION) assigning the CLOSE_DATE a ROW_NUMBER in descending order. This will ensure that each ROW_NUMBER with a value of "1" will be the Max CLOSE_DATE for each PART_ID.

The final SELECT statement simply JOINS the two Cte's on PART_ID, filtering where LastCloseDate = 1 (the ROW_NUMBER assigned in the second CTE).

If I understand the requirements correctly, this should give you the desired results.

Additionally, I removed the filter WHERE PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'OB%' because we're already filtering by PART.STATUS IS NULL and you stated above that an 'O' is placed in this field for Obsolete parts. Also, [DIE] and [ENGR MASTER] have the same value in the 27 rows being pulled before, so I just used the same field and labeled them differently.

```
; WITH Parts AS(
    SELECT prt.PART_ID AS [ENGR MASTER]
            , prt.DESCRIPTION
      FROM PART prt 
     WHERE prt.STATUS IS NULL
       AND prt.PART_ID LIKE 'PCH%'
     GROUP BY prt.ID, prt.DESCRIPTION
)
, LastCloseDate AS(
    SELECT req.PART_ID
            , wrd.CLOSE_DATE
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY req.PART_ID ORDER BY wrd.CLOSE_DATE DESC) AS LastCloseDate
      FROM REQUIREMENT req
     INNER JOIN WORK_ORDER wrd
        ON wrd.BASE_ID = req.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
       AND wrd.LOT_ID = req.WORKORDER_LOT_ID
       AND wrd.SUB_ID = req.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
     WHERE wrd.CLOSE_DATE IS NOT NULL
       AND GETDATE() - (365 * 3) > wrd.CLOSE_DATE
)
SELECT prt.PART_ID AS [DIE]
        , prt.PART_ID AS [ENGR MASTER]
        , prt.DESCRIPTION
        , lst.CLOSE_DATE
  FROM Parts prt
 INNER JOIN LastCloseDate lst
    ON prt.PART_ID = lst.PART_ID
 WHERE LastCloseDate = 1
```

Comment: Hey rhholt, thanks for taking a shot. When I run your code I get 27K rows. below is a small sample of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Hey rhholt, thanks for taking a shot. When I run your code I get 27K rows. Here is a link to the output. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22548767/sampleoutput.xlsx. I think what I need is to filter the REQUIREMENT.PART_ID column by the most recent WORK_ORDER.CLOSE_DATE. since the only part I am concerned with is the most recent used. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: I edited the query, can you try it again. If that doesn't work, can you send me a small sample of the three tables individually so I can build a query that will return the results of the original spreadsheet for just the most recent CLOSE_DATE?

Comment: Unfortunately I still get 27000 lines, however I read a little more about cross apply() and it seems like it would be useful to help understand what is actually happening. I've edited my query above I now get 13K lines. If I could make 4 distinct this would be about 600 entries and may be the data I'm looking for. Alas, I can't figure out how to do it. here is the output. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22548767/sampleoutput.xlsx

Comment: Made some edits, try again and let me know. Again, if this doesn't work, send me a sample of the three tables individually and I can build out a query that gives you the desired results. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get the most recent update to execute. Incorrect syntax line 9

Comment: Fixed.... had a semicolon where there should have been a comma, right to the left of LastCloseDate.